# Google Maps API v3, what counts as a hit if I'm not geocoding?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building an application that will be getting sets of gps coordinates from the database, and then converting them to an array of location objects.  Then it will render a Google map using the API and put markers and pop up info for the markers at the determined locations.  The user will be able to filter to different locations and different markers.  In the documentation it talks a lot about query limits and how fast/how many queries you are allowed to do.  Most of what I've found involves geocoding addresses though, if I'm not geocoding and just using my own coordinates for the markers, then what will be considered a query counted towards the limit?  I need to make sure I'm designing this right and my company has the right access for what we need.  Thanks.

Comment: the only thing that will be counted is the map-load(each time you  create a `google.maps.Map`-instance), the current limit for map-loads is 25.000 per day.

Comment: This answer is available all over google.